# mongodb statistics 5 million doc too slow

Tags: mongodb, performance, aggregation-framework

5 million mongo doc：

```
{
    _id: xxx,
    devID: 123,
    logLevel: 5,
    logTime: 1468464358697
}
```

indexes:
    devID

my aggregate：

```
[
    {$match: {devID: 123}},
    {$group: {_id: {level: "$logLevel"}, count: {$sum: 1}}}
]
```

aggregate result:

```
{ "_id" : { "level" : 5 }, "count" : 5175872 }
{ "_id" : { "level" : 1 }, "count" : 200000 }
```

aggregate explain:

```
numYields:42305
29399ms
```

Q:
if mongo without writing(saving) data, it will take 29 seconds
    if mongo is writing(saving) data, it will take 2 minutes
    my aggregate result need to reply to web, so 29sec or 2min are too long
    How can i solve it? preferably 10 seconds or less
    Thanks all

Comment: Mmm. Index logLevel?

Comment: doesn't seem to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, the aggregation query for `{devID: 123, logLevel:5}` returns a count of 5,175,872 which looks like it counted all the documents in your collection (since you mentioned you have 5 million documents).

In this particular example, I'm guessing that the `{$match: {devID: 123}}` stage matches pretty much every document, hence the aggregation is doing what is essentially a collection scan. Depending on your RAM size, this could have the effect of pushing your working set out of memory, and slow down every other query your server is doing.

If you cannot provide a more selective criteria for the `$match` stage (e.g. by using a range of `logTime` as well as `devID`), then a pre-aggregated report may be your best option.

In general terms, a pre-aggregated report is a document that contains the aggregated information you require, and you update this document every time you insert into the related collection. For example, you could have a single document in a separate collection that looks like:

```
{log:
    {devID: 123,
    levelCount: [
        {level: 5, count: 5175872},
        {level: 1, count: 200000}
    ]
}}
```

where that document is updated with the relevant details every time you insert into the log collection.

Using a pre-aggregated report, you don't need to run the aggregation query anymore. The aggregated information you require is instead available using a single `find()` query instead.

For more examples on pre-aggregated reports, please see https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/use-cases/pre-aggregated-reports/